# Web server java library?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I m looking for a simple java library which would let me make a java web server and share some files. Is there any libraries which would let me achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need a library and not the server itself?

Comment: I would like to make a very simple application which will automatically create a web server and share file across the network..without installing anything except application

Comment: Is JSP support a requirement or is it just for pure static content? There are many lightweight webservers for static content, lighter than Jetty. Even plain Java 1.6 ships with a builtin one (albeit a bit hidden).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jetty - the lightweight web server and servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

There is a host of different web servers which all can do what you want (provided it just is allowing users to download files).

A good, small library with a simple-to-get-started method, is the Acme Laboratory Java pages.

http://acme.com/java/software/Acme.Serve.Serve.html

serves the current directory without any fuzz.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use an [Apache WebServer](http://httpd.apache.org/) setup for this.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the OP tagged `jsp` and Apache HTTPD doesn't support it at all. That might have been the downvote reason :)